# Get into a line from a text file and edit it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, edit

Supposedly I have this line in my text file which has the following format.

```
"Title:Author:Price:QtyAvailable:QtySold"
```

The contents of my text file is shown below

```
 Hello World:Andreas:10.50:10:5
 Lord Of The Rings:Duke:50.15:50:20
    (some other records...)
```

1) User inputs Author and Title.

2) If Program locates the Author+Title, it asks user to Update any of the fields available ( for this case Title, Author, Price etc..

3) For example I will like to update the Price of Hello World book.

4) What can I do to tell the program to extract the contents of the Hello World line, and get into 10.50 to replace the price of the book? (assumes new price of the book will be decided by the user's input)

Hope to get my answer.
Thanks in advance to those who helped!

Comment: You can do it with sed but why would you want to do this with a shell script? It's a bad choice for what amounts to a CRUD app.

Comment: what have you done so far? and what is the question?

Comment: @Kent I have not done anything yet at the moment as I do not know where to start.

Comment: Agree with frankc; this would be much easier in a "real" programming language -- I would personally use Python.  (And I would use a minidatabase, e.g. SQLite.)

Comment: One of the most important things to learn, when you are learning the Unix shell, is to recognize problems that should not be solved in shell, because they need the power of a a more sophisticated programming language.  The task you have described is definitely on the far side of that line.  (That said, trying to do it in shell, as an exercise, will maybe teach you *why* this is such a vital skill.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a something to get you started:

#### Sample Script:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat s.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Author?"
read author

echo "Title?"
read title

grep -c "$title:$author" file > /dev/null # Look for a line with matching values

if [ $? == 0 ]; then # If found then offer to change price
    echo "I found the book, Do you want to update price to what?"
    read newprice
    sed -i "s/\($book:$author\):[^:]*:/\1:$newprice:/" file
fi
```

#### Input Data:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
Hello World:Andreas:10.50:10:5
Lord Of The Rings:Duke:50.15:50:20
```

#### Execution:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] ./s.sh 
Author? 
Andreas
Title? 
Hello World
I found the book, Do you want to update price to what?
40
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
Hello World:Andreas:40:10:5
Lord Of The Rings:Duke:50.15:50:20
```

Comment: thanks for the input. However I know how everything works but just that I am not sure on what actually this line does with its much complexity with the symbols. (sed -i "s/\($book:$author\):[^:]*:/\1:$newprice:/" file), care to explain it?
cheers.

Comment: Sure @Andres. What `sed` is saying that `use -i` option for infile editing for a line that has `$book:$author` together. The values for these variables comes from what user provides at run time. If `sed` files it a line, it groups that information (using parenthesis) and everything else after that i.e price is updated by our variable $newprice. We use `\1` to print the group we setup in substitution part so that we dont have to type it and it becomes more generic.

Comment: Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4) for your reading. :)

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to explain it to me but sadly.. I dont really get it. I understand this part | sed -i "s/($book:$author) | but what i dont get it is this part | :[^:]*:/\1:$newprice: <---

Comment: No worries @Andres. What it says is match a colon and anything after that except for a colon. [^:] is a character class that matches any one character. Putting ^ inside it we are negating the character class. So it says find a colon, then match anything after that which is not a colon and then we put a colon after that. So when sed parses thru the line it sees :price: and what it does is it starts with a colon and the matches all of price and stops when it sees another colon.

Comment: Hi, I really dont really get it. I need more examples to maybe give me a better view on how those symbols work.
Ok what about let's say I will want to update my Title instead? or my QtyAvailable, how could i go about doing it?

Comment: Changing the title would be easy all you need to do is identify the line you want to modify and then do this `sed "s/.[^:]*/Newtitle/" file` this says match everything but not a colon (dot operator matches any character except new lines) and replace it with Newtitle

Comment: For Quantity you can do this `sed "s/\(.*\):\(.*\):\(.*\):.*[^:]:/\1:\2:\3:NewQTY:/" file`

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed like this with variable parameters:

```
# book title:author to be searched
BOOK="Hello World:Andreas"

# price to be updated
PRICE=11.25

# search and update with original backed up with .bak extension
sed -i.bak 's/\('"$BOOK"'\):[^:]*:/\1:'"$PRICE"':/' file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

If you fill-in shell variables into sed command it will look like this:

```
sed 's/\(Hello World:Andreas\):[^:]*:/\1:11.25:/'
```

**match**

```
"$BOOK"                 # match literal text i.e. Hello World:Andreas
\($BOOK\)               # group this text to be back referenced later
:                       # match literal :
[^:]*                   # match 0 or more characters until : is found
:                       # match a :
```

**replacement**

```
\1                      # group # 1 i.e. Hello World:Andreas
:                       # a literal :
$PRICE                  # fill in the new price
:                       # literal :
```

Essentially this sed command is finding text that has `Hello World:Andreas:` followed by *some price value* and then followed by another `:`. Once this patter is found it is replacing that with back-reference # 1 (which is `Hello World:Andreas`) followed by a `:` and then put the new price value and a colon `:`.

**EDIT:** You are highly recommended to read some sed tutorial however as per your comment I am providing you command to update quantity:

```
# book title:author to be searched
BOOK="Hello World:Andreas"

# quantity to be updated
QTY=18

# search and update with original backed up with .bak extension
sed 's/^\('"$BOOK"'\):\([^:]*\):[^"]*:/\1:\2:'"$QTY"':/'
```

Comment: hi thanks for the solution, I have to agree with the others that I have to do it myself before asking, however this issue has been stucked with me for a long time and I still do not have a slight idea on what to do with it.

Comment: hi anubhava, mind explaining the line of sed -i.bak 's/\('"$BOOK"'\):[^:]*:/\1:'"$PRICE"':/' to me and how it works? thanks

Comment: Sure adding some explanation in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I really dont really get it. I need more examples to maybe give me a better view on how those symbols work.
Ok what about let's say I will want to update my Title instead? or my QtyAvailable.  how could i go about doing it?

Comment: Hmm it seems you **unaccepted** my answer, did it not work for you? Anyway I updated my answer to tell you how to edit quantity. Pls allow me to say this `Once you spend some time in understanding regex and sed, now only you will be able to answer these questions of updating individual fields yourself, you will start helping others also with similar problems.`